# How to Over Write CSS the default theme CSS WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I Want to change some default theme CSS and replace it with the required css.
Can anybody define how to do that
!important doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please try the customize option provided by your theme also it's easy to extend the theme and create a child theme

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Be sure to make such customizations as a child theme. Using a child theme lets you upgrade the parent theme without affecting the customizations you’ve made to your site. And that should solve your problem at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Child themes or go to `Appearance >> customize >> custom CSS`  from the admin panel and add your CSS.